# Extending UI-Router-Tabs To Display Form Validation State

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-service

I'm pretty new to Angular and having a problem figuring out how to bind a value from a data service to a customization of the https://github.com/rpocklin/ui-router-tabs project that I have created.

The customization is to display an icon in the tab heading that toggles based on the validation state of the corresponding ui-view. I've wired up a data service that is updated when validation succeeds or fails, and the binding is being "seen" by the controller that renders the tabs.

The problem arises when I attempt to pass this value into the tab data as "options". The value change/icon toggle is not being processed as the validation state changes. If I pass a hard-coded "true" into the tab data, the desired icon is displayed.

```
vm.tabs = [
        {
            heading: "View 1",
            route: "manage.view1",
            options: {
                status: vm.stateService.getForm1State()
            }
        },
        {
            heading: "View 2",
            disable: vm.disableTabs,
            route: "manage.view2",
            options:{
                status: true
            }

        }
    ];
```

This doesn't seem like something that should be that difficult, so I think I'm just missing something obvious about the scoping. Here is a plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/iefvwcffSZmpfy83NGde?p=preview that demonstrates the issue.

Note: should be tagged as ui-router-tabs, but I lack the reputation to create the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
options: {
  status: vm.stateService.getForm1State()
}
```

Since `stateService.getForm1State()` returns a boolean value, this value will be copied and assigned as the value of the `status` property.

So when this code has executed once it will for example be:

```
options: {
  status: false
}
```

The `options` object won't react to any changes within the `stateService`.

An easy solution is to have `stateService.getForm1State()` return an object instead.

For example:

```
function stateService() {

  var form1IsValid = {
    status: false
  };

  return {
    getForm1State: getForm1State,
    setForm1State: setForm1State
  };

  function getForm1State() {
    return form1IsValid;
  }

  function setForm1State(newValue) {
    form1IsValid.status = newValue;
    return;
  }
```

Then make the `options` object refer to the same object:

```
options: vm.stateService.getForm1State()
```

Now whenever you have:

```
options.status
```

It will be the same as:

```
vm.stateService.getForm1State().status
```

And it will correctly reflect the changes.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/KjXVSSMJbLw7uod0ac6O?p=preview

Comment: Thanks so much, I appreciate the help! I knew that should not have been hard, but just couldn't see the problem.